# Relationship between channels/entries

Tags: entries, relations, channels

I need some help. Really struggle understanding how to build relationships between channels/entries.

Context/Want:
I have two separate channels:
1. "Plant catalogue"
2. "Plant care"
I want to re-use the entries from "Plant catalogue" across the whole website wherever I need it accesing speicifc fields.

What I have:
"Plant care" has an entries field type to help build the relationship with "Plant catalogue": field name: "plantEntity"
"Plant catalogue" has an asset field that include a photo of the plant. fiel name: "plantPhoto"

My code so far:

```
{% set plantcareListing = craft.entries().section('plantCare').limit(null)%}
{% set entries = plantcareListing.all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
  {% for image in entry.plantEntity %} {# how do I access the asset field "plantPhoto" here? :( #}
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
  {% endfor %}

  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would appreciate your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s important to understand that using relations fields in the template works similar to using `craft.entries`. They return a [element query object](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/), for example `entry.plantEntity` in your entries loop. And you need to call the `all()` method on them to query for the elements. The same applies to querying for the asset elements in your inner entries loop.

```
{% set plantCares = craft.entries
    .section('plantCare')
    .all() %}

{% for plantCare in plantCares %}
    {% for plantEntity in plantCare.plantEntity.all() %}
        {% for plantPhoto in plantEntity.plantPhoto.all() %}
            <img src="{{ plantPhoto.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ plantPhoto.title }}">
        {% endfor %}

        {{ plantEntity.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You should generally avoid querying in a loop though, and use [eager-loading](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) instead.

```
{% set plantCares = craft.entries
    .section('plantCare')
    .with([
        'plantEntity',
        'plantEntity.plantPhoto'
    ])
    .all() %}

{% for plantCare in plantCares %}
    {% for plantEntity in plantCare.plantEntity %}
        {% for plantPhoto in plantEntity.plantPhoto %}
            <img src="{{ plantPhoto.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ plantPhoto.title }}">
        {% endfor %}

        {{ plantEntity.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you’ve got many `plantCare` entries consider [paginating](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/paginate.html) through them.

Comment: Thank you so much carlcs! Works like magic and I now understand the concepts!

Comment: I’m glad it helped @DorinVancea, the docs on element queries are very good in my opinion.